# Convert Magento Dropdown to Buttons or list

Tags: jquery, magento

Is there a possibility to convert the classic dropdown from product configurable view to a list of buttons inline with Jquery, Javascript or CSS3 ?

This is an example of website: http://demo.extensionsmall.com/color-swatch-examples/configurable-product-with-popup-boxes.html

I will appreciate if can get some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless, doing this through an extension is the proper way of modifying this.

Here is a link to a github of an extension to do something similar. Not sure about compatibility with 1.8 but it could work as a reference.

https://github.com/dbashyal/Magento-Configurable-Products-Radio-Select

Comment: Will, something such as this work for you?  If not I can help push you towards some other ways.